# Form submission failed to update database record

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to update data in a database from a form but when I click save the data is not updated. It should be updating data in the database, which is not working. I already tried a few tutorial but still not working. Here is my code:

```
 <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','','bookstore_db');
 $currentuser = $_SESSION['username'];   
 $select = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name='$currentuser'";
 $run = mysqli_query($conn,$select);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
     $user_name = $row['user_name'];
     $user_email = $row['user_email'];
     $user_password = $row['user_password'];
?>
 <div class="row">
   <!-- left column -->
   <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="text-center">
       <div class="profile-pic-div">
         <img src="image/image.jpg" id="image">
         <input type="file" id="file">
         <label for="file" id="uploadBtn">Choose Photo</label>
       </div>
       <script src="app.js"></script>
     </div>
   </div>
   

   <!-- edit form column -->
   <div class="col-md-9 personal-info">
     <h3><b>Personal info</b></h3>
     
     <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Username:</label>
         <div class="col-lg-8">
           <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['user_name']; ?>">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
         <div class="col-lg-8">
           <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['user_email']; ?>">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Password:</label>
         <div class="col-lg-8">
           <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['user_password']; ?>">
         </div>
       </div>
       <center><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes"></center> 
   </div>
     </form>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
<hr>

<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','','bookstore_db');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
 
 $euser_name = $_POST['user_name'];
 $euser_email = $_POST['user_email'];
 $euser_password = $_POST['user_password'];
 
 $update = "UPDATE user SET user_name='$euser_name',user_email='$euser_email',user_password='$euser_password' WHERE user_name='$currentuser'";
 
 $run_update = mysqli_query($conn,$update);
 if($run_update === true)
 {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Data Updated") </script>';
 }
     else
 {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Data Not Updated") </script>';
 }
}



?>
```

What could the missing code be, or did I overlook something here?

Comment: `not working` means what exactly?

Comment: when I update data, it didn't save into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be multiple issues. I'm here to point out one of them.

Your `<form>` element has no [method attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method). By default, forms are submitted with the `GET` method, but your PHP are reading results from the [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) superglobal variable that should be submitted by `POST` method. So when your form is submitted, you will get only an empty `$_POST` array. Thus the database update will make the user fields all empty.

To fix this, simply change this line:

```php
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

to this:

```php
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
```

P.S. Your way to do query opens to [SQL injection attacks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Instead of using [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) on a constructed string, using a combination of [mysqli_prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and [mysqli_stmt_execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) would be much safer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you missed something,
your input doesn't have a name, as you do on the submit input.
so the PHP won't recognize your POST

=> **name="user_name"**

```
<input class="form-control" name="user_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['user_name']; ?>">
```